# Can't install ggplot2 at debian 7.6 in R

Tags: linux, r, package, debian

Today i'm trying to install a good library for visualization and create graphics, named "*ggplot2*", but i actually have a problems with installation!

There what i have in output:

> Installing package into ‘/home/hamsternik/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) 
>   also installing the dependencies ‘munsell’, ‘scales’, ‘testthat’
>
> trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/munsell_0.4.2.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 91026 bytes (88 Kb) opened URL ==================================================
>
> downloaded 88 Kb trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/scales_0.2.4.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 40093 bytes (39 Kb) opened URL ==================================================
>
> downloaded 39 Kb trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/testthat_0.8.1.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 40777 bytes (39 Kb) opened URL ==================================================
>
> downloaded 39 Kb trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggplot2_1.0.0.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2351447 bytes (2.2 Mb) opened URL ==================================================
>
> downloaded 2.2 Mb * installing *source* package ‘munsell’ ... ** package ‘munsell’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked ** R ** inst ** preparing package for lazy loading Error : package ‘colorspace’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘munsell’ * removing ‘/home/hamsternik/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/munsell’
>
> Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘munsell’ had non-zero exit status * installing *source* package ‘testthat’ ... ** package ‘testthat’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked ** R ** inst ** preparing package for lazy loading Error : package ‘digest’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘testthat’ * removing ‘/home/hamsternik/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/testthat’
>
> Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘testthat’ had non-zero exit status ERROR: dependency ‘munsell’ is not available for package ‘scales’ * removing ‘/home/hamsternik/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/scales’
>
> Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘scales’ had non-zero exit status ERROR: dependency ‘scales’ is not available for package ‘ggplot2’ * removing ‘/home/hamsternik/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/ggplot2’
>
> Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status The downloaded source packages are in ‘/tmp/RtmpDEeNck/downloaded_packages’

I actually use a debian-stable system (v.7.6) and the next decision was to install "*r-cran-ggplot2*" in the console. 
And when i install them, i think about i having this library, but when i write in Rstudio: *library(ggplot2)*, i take next message: *Error: package ‘ggplot2’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it*

But i have a the up-to-date version - 3.1.1! 
I really don't find any good answers for that question! PLeas, help!

Comment: Did you try reinstalling all the offending packages that were mentioned in the output... (colorspace, digest, ...)

Comment: How about `install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies=TRUE)`?

Comment: i make exactly, how you write! and that output is after this command

Comment: You didn't write it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, problem is actually done!

All what i make - remove all packages, including '*R-cran-.**' and again install it, but not install all packages which i find by the *search* command in konsole. I install only r-base, next i install R studio. Thus i can straightforwardly install every package with dependencies  and they will be actually installed!