# Not able to deploy shiny app in rstudio server

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, rstudio-server

I was trying to run a shiny app in RStudio but everytime i tried to run the document it refuses to run it saying

```
error in library(shiny) : there is no package called ‘shiny’
```

This happens also after i installed the shiny app.

```
    Installing package into ‘/home/mrshekar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/shiny_1.1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2350156 bytes (2.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.2 MB

* installing *source* package ‘shiny’ ...
** package ‘shiny’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  shared object ‘httpuv.so’ not found
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘shiny’
* removing ‘/home/mrshekar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/shiny’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘shiny’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpjZEHLD/downloaded_packages’
```

Something similar happens when i try to deploy the shiny web app in the server. It says

```
Download the Shiny app now?
```

Everytime i start a new app eve after i have installed the packages.
Please help. Thanks

Comment: Installation of shiny failed due to httpuv. What happens if you first install httpuv?

Comment: Doesn't help even after installing that

Comment: What is the error now when you install shiny package after installing httpuv?

Comment: What is the output of `library(httpuv)`?

Comment: {shared object ‘httpuv.so’ not found} @RalfStubner

Comment: Same as before installing httpuv @ReshamWadhwa

Comment: And what is the error message you get from `install.packages("httpuv")`?

Comment: failed to lock directory ‘/home/mrshekar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’ for modifying
Try removing ‘/home/mrshekar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/00LOCK-httpuv’ @RalfStubner

Comment: Do you have an admin for that server? Errors like that should be easy to sort out with access to the server. If not, you have to go through this step by step. Maybe somebody has time to help you via chat.

Comment: [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382209/r-install-packages-returns-failed-to-create-lock-directory/14389028) . It basically says that while installing httpuv (in your case), somehow the process got interrupted abnormally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer in [Can't install ggplot2 at debian 7.6 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228621/cant-install-ggplot2-at-debian-7-6-in-r?rq=1) works.
But after you do that manually enter all the packages you want to install in it

Answer (score 1):

It already happened to me. 
I don't know why, but R was not able to install shiny. So the thing i did is to install it manually. I mean, just download the package from here:
 https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shiny/index.html and paste the shiny folder in C:\Users\your_username\Documents\R\win-library\3.3. If it doesn't work, just install the dependencies.

Comment: We have to do it for all the packages(like ggplot2) that are to be installed or just the shiny?

Comment: And there it wouln't help as this whole thing is happening on rstudio server. Where you experiencing this problem on rstudio server online?

Comment: I don't think this will help since the OP uses Linux. CRAN has binaries only for Windows and MacOS.

Comment: @RalfStubner you can download the tar.gz file and use gunzip even in linux I guess

Comment: @rahulyadav i did this only for `shiny` `later` and `httpuv`

Comment: The `tar.gz` files contain the sources, while the `zip` files contain binaries. It won't help to copy sources into the place where binaries are expected.

Comment: you can install package from source giving R the path